# How to declare a variable name consisting of other varables (MATLAB)?

Tags: variables, matlab

I have a Variable that needs to be dependent on another variable inside a loop:

```
for n=1:100

newfilename="NEW_FILE_1.txt"

end
```

where the "1" needs to be what ever n is: So 1 for the first loop and 2 for the second loop and so on and so forth.

How do you set up declaring "newfilename" to have the variable "n" variable inside its name?

Thanks

Comment: Shot in the dark: newfilename="NEW_FILE_",n,".txt"

Comment: I have found out there are many ways to do it...sprintf, fprintf...and some other like the answers below! Thanks everyone for your help! good answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for n=1:100
    newfilename = ['NEW_FILE_' num2str(n) '.txt'];
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Or use SPRINTF in the for loop:

```
for n=1:100
    newfilename = sprintf('NEW_FILE_%d.txt',n);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you want, at the end of the loop, to have a series of variables called newfilename1, newfilename2... etc.

The short answer to this is: don't*. Instead, place your data in an cell array
as follows

```
for n=1:100

   newFilename{n} = sprintf('NEW_FILE_%i.txt', n)

end
```

You can then refer to your variables as newfilename{1}, newFilename{2}, etc...

* There is a way to do what you want using the function eval, and the method has been answered in other posts. But it's just bad practice.

Comment: You don't have to use cell array if newFilename supposed to be used only once inside the for-loop. The OP didn't say that he wanted to create newFilename1, newFilename2, etc. Good point anyway.

Comment: The question explicitly says "how to declare a variable name consisting of other variables"... I agree that the rest of the question is fuzzy, but that's what I was trying to address.